# Looping JSON data into Redis with HSET

Tags: node.js, redis

Currently I'm adding already paginated data from mongoose query to redis so that I can pull it based on the key `'listings-page-' + currentPage` I'm trying to `hget` the data that I just for looped into redis, but currently it's returning undefined when trying to return all results with that key.

I'm guessing its an append issue, but I haven't seen in related commands [here](https://redis.io/commands/hset) that is related to appending data for hset redis data. I appreciate any help!

```
             .then(documents => {

          for (let i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {

            let docs = JSON.stringify(documents[i]);
            let listingId = documents[i]._id.toString();
            client.hset('listings-page-' + currentPage, listingId, docs);


          }
          client.hget('listings-page-' + currentPage, (err, val) => console.log((val)));
```

Comment: Did you consider using the RedisJSON module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it can be happening because asynchronous loop behaviour.

Did you try to write that code using the forEach iterator over the collection? It will look like this:

```
    documents.forEach(document => {
client.hset('listings-page-' + currentPage,
document._id.toString(),
JSON.stringify(document));});
```

There are some other third packages to handle promises (like bluebird) that allows you to deal with some other scenarios like race condition, parallel iterations and so on.

Let me know if there is anything else I can do to help you!

My example (requires redis running on localhost:6379)

```
const redis = require('redis');

const client = redis.createClient(6379, 'localhost' );
client.on('connect', function() {
  console.log('Redis client connected');
  Save();
});

const documents =
  [{_id: '000'}, {_id: '654'}, {_id: '789'},
    {_id: '111'}, {_id: '222'}, {_id: '333'}];
/**
 *
 */
async function Save () {
  console.log('saving');
  const key = 'listings-page-1';
  await documents.forEach((document) => {
    client.hset(key,
        document._id.toString(),
        'lorem ipsum', (err, obj) => console.log(obj));
    console.log(key);
  });
  console.log('saved');
  client.hgetall(key, (err, val) => console.log((val)));
};
```

Comment: I tried the forEach iterator way too, but it also returns undefined. documents definitely has data

Comment: I have built an example to reproduce the same scenario. And it works fine! Something I've found different between my example and yours is that client.hget needs two parameters (key, field) and hgetall just one (key). Which one do you need?

Comment: Thanks for the example. Pointing out the hgetall and hget parameters helped. I guess I got mixed up. I was able to get everything from the cache with 2 parameters and was able to do an hget with ```documents[2]._id.toString()``` as second parameter. Thanks for the help and explanation!